# Get checked checkbox value on array

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have data value in form input. How to retrieve checked checkbox state above  and hold it in an array.

```js
function test() {
  var main = [];
  var cboxes = document.getElementsByName('mailId[]');
  var len = cboxes.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var cok = (i + (cboxes[i].checked ? ' checked ' : ' unchecked ') + cboxes[i].value);
    console.log(cok);
    // if checked main.push(value)
    // else delete value in array main

  }
}
```

```html
<th><input type="checkbox" class="messageCheckbox" id="checkbox1" value="13" name="mailId[]" onClick="test()"></th>

<th><input type="checkbox" class="messageCheckbox" id="checkbox1" value="14" name="mailId[]" onClick="test()"></th>
```

I made a log, but the log doesn't take the value from the checkbox above.

If the check box is checked then the value will be entered into the array, if it is unchecked the value will be deleted from the array storage

Comment: You know this is all plain JS and there's no jquery here? Are you actually using jquery at all in your page, or not?

Comment: oh sorry hehehe

Comment: I mean, you get the value of an input with .value, as you've written. You can confirm this by using it directly outside of your existing logic.

Comment: can u example ?

Comment: The code you've shown appears to collect the data correctly - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n4bjy9wc/ . It's a bit unclear exactly what the problem is...can you clarify?

Comment: Also, `id`s need to be unique in HTML (well, everywhere, but for your question, specifically in HTML), but both of these elements have `id="checkbox1"`. You're currently not using these ids, but if you ever tried to do `document.getElementById('checkbox1')`, you might not get the element you're expecting.

Comment: (IDs need to be unique anywhere, not just in HTML!!)

Comment: how to get VALUE in cekbox bro

Comment: i need example bro

Comment: @devgomar Who is "bro"? You have no idea if any of us are bros. Try to just refer to people by their username then a) it's clear who you mean to speak to, and b) you don't accidentally assume anyone is male (or female, or from another planet, etc). (P.S. I'm not offended, it's just some friendly advice to avoid any possible trouble in future :-))

Comment: `how to get VALUE in cekbox`...your code already gets the value. What do you think `cboxes[i].value` does? If that's not what you mean, please ask a clearer and more specific question.

Comment: I converted your code into a live demo and added the log statement you said you'd included by which wasn't in the code. I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creates array from checkboxes. On click, check for checkbox status, based upon that push or splice that value from the array.

Example:

```js
let main = {};
main['value'] = [];

function test() {
  var checkbox = Array.from(document.getElementsByName("mailId[]"));

  for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
    var sbVal = checkbox[i].value;

    if (checkbox[i].checked && main.value.indexOf(sbVal) < 0) {
      main.value.push(checkbox[i].value);
      continue;
    }

    if (checkbox[i].checked === false && main.value.indexOf(sbVal) >= 0) {
      var j = main.value.indexOf(sbVal);
      main.value.splice(j, 1);
    }
  }

  console.log(main['value']);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="messageCheckbox" id="checkbox1" value="13" name="mailId[]" onClick="test()">

<input type="checkbox" class="messageCheckbox" id="checkbox1" value="14" name="mailId[]" onClick="test()">
```

Note: **id** must be unique otherwise it's rule violation.